# Soft lock update error

Tags: corda

We do explicit soft-locking with
serviceHub.vaultService.softLockReserve(txBuilder.lockId, NonEmptySet.of(balanceStateS2R.ref))

Things were working until today when we got this exception repeatedly.
And now we cannot run the flow anymore.  There was no double-spend going on.  What is causing it and how can we get out of it?

*[m*[1;31mE 17:01:57-0500 [Node thread] vault.NodeVaultService.softLockReserve - soft lock update error attempting to reserve states for acace05e-b0fb-4d4e-9b96-a7d0d4728f68 and [392D84F9CF931F17438399D36607CAFDB549C02A5E7B63E8F8D2B2FADE1AFF57(1)]")
                    Soft locking error: Attempted to reserve [392D84F9CF931F17438399D36607CAFDB549C02A5E7B63E8F8D2B2FADE1AFF57(1)] for acace05e-b0fb-4d4e-9b96-a7d0d4728f68 but only 0 rows available.

Comment: I've raised a JIRA to add a function to release soft-locked states without providing a UUID here: https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-944.

Comment: Thanks, Joel.  
In my case, since I am doing soft locking within a flow, I have the lockId for release at the end of the flow.
The question is: what happens if the flow has an exception? I thought the framework will automatically release all softlocks with or without the flow exceptions.

Comment: Soft locking is only auto-managed by the flow manager for fungible asset spending. Any explicit usage requires strict reserve & release consistency (including in error scenarios).

Answer (score 1):

Without more context (e.g. what actions the flow is executing), I cannot provide an accurate answer, but some points to raise:

- The error message indicates that the previously locked state has been consumed in some way (perhaps by the flow that originally locked it) and was not explicitly released after consumption
- Use the `softLockRelease()` API call to explicitly release states that have been explicitly previously locked

Comment: Thanks, Jose.  Isn't it true any more that the flow soft locks are automatically released when the flow terminates or errors.
Per the doc,
"Upon building a new transaction to perform some action for a set of states on a contract, a developer must explicitly register any states they may wish to hold until that transaction is committed to the ledger. These states will be effectively ‘soft locked’ (not usable by any other transaction) until the developer explicitly releases these or the flow terminates or errors (at which point they are automatically released)."

Comment: Soft locking is only auto-managed by the flow manager for fungible asset spending. Any explicit usage requires strict reserve & release consistency (including in error scenarios). I'll review the docs.